# How would I have one view controller access a variable from another view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface

Everything I've seen on stack is passing the data from an input, onto another view controller on a button press. Let's say I have `var banana` that is an array of dictionaries, but once my function in ViewA.swift is done loading up `banana`, I want another viewController, say ViewB.swift to manipulate that data as it sees fit. I do NOT have a segue going from one view controller to the other.
EDIT: It's actually two TableViewControllers****

I've looked into NSNotificationCenter, but that doesn't seem to work with my variable type, which is an array of dictionaries

Comment: So you want to pass var banana to ViewB.Swift? What you have tried? Have you create the property in ViewB?

Comment: How is ViewB related to ViewA, or are they related at all?

Comment: They are not at all. There are no segues. The only relation is they are both ViewControllers, and they are both within the same project.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSNotificationCenter` for accessing data.

Try Below code

```
//Sent notification 

 let dictionary = ["key":"value"]    
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("passData", object: nil, userInfo: dictionary)

//Receive  notification 

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
 selector:"myMethod:", name: "passData", object: nil)

//Receive  notification method

 func myMethod(notification: NSNotification){
 print("data: \(notification.userInfo!["key"])")
```

Comment: so I tried this but it's telling me that my variable does not work, as it is an array of dictionaries, and not just a dictionary. I guess I can for loop through it but there's 100 dictionaries >_> can i cast it or something?

Comment: Okay actually I just looped through my array, and added the dictionaries using the sent notification. I then put the code you provided me into the second viewcontroller under viewDidAppear. Both the function and the "receive notification" section. but it doesn't do anything. I assume I have to call the function, but I'm not sure what the argument is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have given all ViewControllers an identifier, then instantiate them with:

```
guard let viewControllerB = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerB") as? ViewControllerB else {
    fatalError(); return
}
// then access the variable/property of ViewControllerB
viewControllerB.banana = whatEver
```

**Added for clarification**

This one works for me.

Just make sure that you have given the TableViewController an identifier otherwise you will not be able to instantiate it. Also make sure that you cast the result of instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier to your TableViewController class otherwise you won't be able to access it's variables (I've seen that you were struggling with this; if you get an error that UIViewController doesn't have a member "myArray" then you probably have forgotten to cast the result)

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var myArray = [String]()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func someEventWillTriggerThisFunction() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let tableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TableViewController") as? TableViewController else {
            fatalError(); return
        }
        tableViewController.myArray = ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]
        /* if you want to present the ViewController use this: */
        self.presentViewController(tableViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this cause memory issues? I'm hazy on instantiation with swift, but very familiar with objects in Java and how they communicate with one another. SO the above code, I run it in viewControllerA, instantiate an instance of viewControllerB within it, and then I have acecss to viewControllerB's variables. Would this carry over to the view linked to viewControllerB?

Comment: Why should it? 
You are holding one instance of viewControllerA and one instance of viewControllerB. Yes you are able to access viewControllerB's variables. 

If you change the variables of viewControllerB in the instance you are holding in viewControllerA they are visible in viewControllerB.

Comment: I get an error running that code and it says "error expected declaration"

Comment: Actually upon further review, I am trying to have a TableViewController get data from a viewcontroller, and it tells me it can't :(

Comment: You have to "push" the variable from ViewController to TableViewController not the other way.

Comment: I've added a more precise example in my answer. Hope that helps. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Without using segue, you can instantiate the View controller, and set the public parameteres.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! ViewB

/* Here you have the reference to the view, so you can set the parameters*/

vc.parameterInViewB = banana

/* At this point you can present the view to the user.*/

self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: so when I do vc.parameterInViewB = "hello", it tells me that vc has no member "parameterInViewB", but it most definitely does as I added it as a var.Exact error is "Value of type "UIViewController has no member 'CategorizedArray'"

Comment: in the end of 2 line the there is a cast, as! ViewB, you need it. in yout error is clear that you still using the default object "UIViewController"